# send email to access package owner using logic app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-entra-id

In Entra ID, I need to check the access packages created before 180days. If there are no active assignment and no members in the scope group I need to send email to access package owner about this. How can this achieved by using Microsoft Graph API ?

Note: I have more than 1000 access packages.

Thanks.

Comment: You’re question is far too high level. You’re asking for a solution but really, you need to break the problem down into smaller chunks and target a specific issue you’re having.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I won't be able to build the full solution, but only be listing the steps needed to achieve it.

1 - You will need to register an app in Entra ID and give it permission to Graph. (Likely the EntitlementManagement.Read.All permission) ([check other permissions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference))

2 - In your logic app, you need to add a HTTP call to get a bearer token using the details of the application Id.
Use the bearer token in the authorization header for the next calls

3 - You will need to call [entitlement management API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/entitlementmanagement-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to get the data you need

These endpoints use OData, you can apply filters to only get ones you are interested in.